# When did Gabriel go into hiding?

Tags: supernatural

In supernatural we find out that The Trickster is in fact Gabriel, the Arch Angel. He mentions on numerous occasions that he went into 'witness protection'. When did this happen? Kali knows him as Loki, so that must set some sort of timeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost impossible to determine when Gabriel went into hiding for the following reasons:

- The Bible and other related texts are inaccurate representations of divine interactions with Men.
- Since they are not history, any attempts at correlation are difficult at best.
- Language used in the TV series Supernatural may be very different from that which is used in religious text, hence the potential confusion. We are forced to use things we DO know to infer what we don't know.

**FACTS - Things we know:**

- The Viking Age was considered to be from the 8th to 11th Century AD. This is the time when humans most strongly worshiped the Norse/Teutonic deities. Their influences can be seen as early as 600 AD.
- Assuming that to be same in the Supernatural universe, during this time Gabriel would have been pretending to be Loki while hiding from the Angels. Does this mean there were actual beings who WERE the Teutonic deities besides him?

**RELIGIOUS TEXTS**

- The Mishneh Torah was compiled between 1170 and 1180. It is presumed the wisdom compiled within was known centuries before that time.
- Muslims believe the Quran to have been verbally revealed through Angel Jibrīl (Gabriel) from God to Muhammad gradually over a period of approximately 23 years beginning on 22nd December 609 CE, when Muhammad was 40, and concluding in 632 CE, the year of his death.
- Earliest parts of the Bible are thought to have been compiled 1445 BC continuously until the 1st century AD.

**SUPERNATURAL**

There is a huge period in which Gabriel might have wandered the Earth before interacting with the Norse acting as The Trickster (aka Loki). He was last reported repeating the word of God to Muhammad 600 years after the birth of Christ.

- If we assume all of Gabriel's visitations in scripture were actually him, then the Supernatural series has a very different story of Heaven and the Fall of Lucifer.
- Most of Gabriel's visitations take place either BC or very early AD. If the various versions of the Abrahamic religions have a period of time to have occurred most started as early as 3500 years ago, making them 1500-2000 BC give or take.
- The implication of this is that Lucifer got tossed out of Heaven relatively recently, comparatively speaking, making demons a relatively new development, circa 2000 BC.

### **SPECULATION**

**Lucifer having a recent Fall from Heaven doesn't square with religious text which indicated that he fell long before Man ever existed. Perhaps we are looking at three different events.**

1. Religious texts talk about the the Fall of Lucifer from Heaven. Strongly documented.
2. Religious texts also indicate the Creation of Hell by Lucifer or God depending on who you ask. This is still a period of time that is pre-Man.
3. Supernatural talks about the Binding of Lucifer and Lucifer being absent from Hell while imprisoned.

It is this period after the Fall of Lucifer but before the Caging of Lucifer, let's say around the turn of the millennia (0-700 AD) that Gabriel stopped doing divine visitations with his last visit to Muhammad in 632 CE.

- Gabriel left Heaven and began dodging his warring brothers dropping off the angelic radar. He would have had plenty of time to pal around Europe pretending to be a deity of that warlike period.
- So this could square with the creation of Lucifer's Cage and the legends of the [66 seals to bind Lucifer](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=The_66_Seals) having more to do with Men than Angels. Lucifer was bound when Men were reaching an ascendancy.

Comment: Is it at all possible that gabriel, in the supernatural world, was doing divine revelation from under cover?

Comment: As long as the receiver of the event was just human, I don't see why not. Humans shouldn't be able to tell the difference,...

Comment: Yes. We saw Odin and Baldur both in that episode. Minor deities seem much less powerful than the Abrahamic god, even less powerful than archangels (Gabriel/Loki excepted). It's difficult to reconcile them as creations of the Abrahamic god, and personally I tend to think of them as "uncreated" along with God and Death. Perhaps their power is related to a more recent "birth", or perhaps they were born weak.

Comment: @Thaddeus I think there is a typo here when talking about Muhammad - Muhammad was alive 600 years after not before the birth of Christ.

Comment: Yes, I noted that by using the CE reference: Common Era (also Current Era or Christian Era), abbreviated as CE, is an alternative designation for the calendar era originally introduced by 6th-century Christian monk Dionysius Exiguus, traditionally identified with Anno Domini (abbreviated AD).

Comment: I think he's talking about this: "to Muhammad 600 years before the birth of Christ." According to Muhammad, Gabriel's first revelation to him happened when he was 40, which is 610 ***CE***, not ***BCE*** (and he continued to receive revelations until he died in 632)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the call.

Comment: @Thaddeus you also missed: "It is this period after the Fall of Lucifer but before the Caging of Lucifer, let's say *around the turn of the millennia or the birth of Christ, (0 AD) that Gabriel stopped doing divine visitations**." No islam? I'm not criticising this point, I just often wonder how islam fits in with the Judeo-Christian mythos in supernatural?

Comment: They have not done much with the Islamic branch of the Abrahamic religions, likely to keep controversy down and viewership up. Americans and their socially engineered Islami-phobia are simply best left undisturbed, and I applaud their decision to do so.

Answer (score 2):

We know that he fled heaven to escape Michael and Lucifer's constant fighting, it must have happened *before* Lucifer was banished to hell. That puts his flight from Heaven well before recorded human history.

He appears to have taken on the guise of Loki some time later, after making friends with the pagan gods, but there's no telling how long he wandered around the Earth before that.

Comment: Then who was the angel in the Torah, Bible and Quran?

Comment: Who knows; we don't even know what those books say in the *Supernatural* world. We know that *our* Bible/Torah/Qu'ran don't match the facts of *Supernatural* at least with regards to Eve, Jesus, or those versions that include Lilith; perhaps the got Gabriel wrong too. Or maybe he popped back up to Heaven a few times to act as God's messenger. (We have to presume God, at least, knew where he was and could call him at any time.)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield We know that demons are merely the souls of humans tortured in Hell until they "change". Lilith is and was a popular name for a long time... just because there is a demon named Lilith, it doesn't mean that it was *that* Lilith, or that *that* Lilith did not exist as well. Same for Eve. As for Jesus, I accept that when they mention him it is the same as the Jesus we're thinking of, and that that history is different than what it recorded in the Bible.